# Return to Previous Variable with If/Else/Elif

Tags: python

So I am working on a coding project as I learn python. It is a relatively simple Choose Your Own Adventure game. I thought I had everything laid out properly, but when the user chooses "swim" for var choice2, it should give the game over message and terminate. However, when I run it and choose "swim" for choice2, it gives the Game Over message, but then moves on to choice11 input. I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. Code below:

```
print("Welcome to Treasure Island.")
print("Your mission is to find the treasure.")

choice1 = input("You\'re at a crossroad. There are three paths here. Do you want to go west, east, or south?").lower()

if choice1 == "west":
    choice2 = input("You have entered a forest clearing, with a lake in the middle. Do you wait for the ferry, "
                    "swim across, or go back east?").lower()
    if choice2 == "wait":
        choice3 = input("You board the ferry and it takes you across the lake. "
                        "You see a house. Do you enter or return across the lake?").lower()
        if choice3 == "enter":
            print("It is dark inside the house. Suddenly you hear a growl as the light flares. "
                  "You are eaten by a grue. Game Over.")
        else:
            input(choice2)
    elif choice2 == "swim":
        print("You attempt to swim across, but suddenly you are attacked by a lake monster. Game Over.")
    elif choice2 == "east":
        input(choice1)
if choice1 == "east":
    print("You come to a dead end in the forest. You are struck by several arrows from nowhere. Game Over.")
else:
    choice11 = input("You move down the path and come to a fork in the road. Do you continue south or go east?").lower()
    if choice11 == "south":
        print("You come upon a treasure chest. When you open it, it is a mimic, with sharp nasty teeth. Game Over.")
    else:
        print("You come upon a veritable treasure hoard! You win!")
```

Comment: After the `swim` choice, your code goes on to `if choice1 == "east":`, which is false, so the `else` block is executed.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that does the "terminate" part. What leads you to believe your code should terminate on that line? Python doesn't understand that the string "Game Over" means "exit the program"; that's on you to write.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this:

```
if choice1 == "east":
```

should be this:

```
elif choice1 == "east":
```

What's happening in the current code is that the entire first `if choice1 == "west"` block is standalone.  So after the "choice2" logic completes, that whole `if` block exits.  The code then moves on to the next `if` block, which is `if choice1 == "east"`.  That condition is `false`, so control enters the `else` block.

By making the second top-level `if` an `elif` you put all three of those top-level blocks into the same overall conditional evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Welcome to Treasure Island.")
print("Your mission is to find the treasure.")

choice1 = input("You\'re at a crossroad. There are three paths here. Do you want to go west, east, or south?").lower()

if choice1 == "west":
    choice2 = input("You have entered a forest clearing, with a lake in the middle. Do you wait for the ferry, "
                    "swim across, or go back east?").lower()
    if choice2 == "wait":
        choice3 = input("You board the ferry and it takes you across the lake. "
                        "You see a house. Do you enter or return across the lake?").lower()
        if choice3 == "enter":
            print("It is dark inside the house. Suddenly you hear a growl as the light flares. "
                  "You are eaten by a grue. Game Over.")
        else:
            input(choice2)
    elif choice2 == "swim":
        print("You attempt to swim across, but suddenly you are attacked by a lake monster. Game Over.")
    elif choice2 == "east":
        input(choice1)
elif choice1 == "east":
    print("You come to a dead end in the forest. You are struck by several arrows from nowhere. Game Over.")
else:
    choice11 = input("You move down the path and come to a fork in the road. Do you continue south or go east?").lower()
    if choice11 == "south":
        print("You come upon a treasure chest. When you open it, it is a mimic, with sharp nasty teeth. Game Over.")
    else:
        print("You come upon a veritable treasure hoard! You win!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly correct. In order to end the program, you need to either use `exit()` which will prompt the user for closing the program, or `return 0` with a function. This will end the program automatically by `returning False`. Here's how you can do that:

```
def adventure():
  print("Welcome to Treasure Island.")
  print("Your mission is to find the treasure.")

  choice1 = input("You\'re at a crossroad. There are three paths here. Do you want to go west, east, or south?").lower()

  if choice1 == "west":
    choice2 = input("You have entered a forest clearing, with a lake in the middle. Do you wait for the ferry, "
                    "swim across, or go back east?").lower()
    if choice2 == "wait":
        choice3 = input("You board the ferry and it takes you across the lake. "
                        "You see a house. Do you enter or return across the lake?").lower()
        if choice3 == "enter":
            print("It is dark inside the house. Suddenly you hear a growl as the light flares. "
                  "You are eaten by a grue. Game Over.")
            return 0  # Here you need to use it
        else:
            input(choice2)
    elif choice2 == "swim":
        print("You attempt to swim across, but suddenly you are attacked by a lake monster. Game Over.")
        return 0 # Here you need to use it
    elif choice2 == "east":
        input(choice1)
  elif choice1 == "east": # Also, this should be an elif as you already have an if statement i.e. if choice1 == "west"
    print("You come to a dead end in the forest. You are struck by several arrows from nowhere. Game Over.")
    return 0    # Here you need to use it 
  else:
    choice11 = input("You move down the path and come to a fork in the road. Do you continue south or go east?").lower()
    if choice11 == "south":
        print("You come upon a treasure chest. When you open it, it is a mimic, with sharp nasty teeth. Game Over.")
        return 0 # Here you need to use it
    else:
        print("You come upon a veritable treasure hoard! You win!")

adventure()
```

Output:

```
Welcome to Treasure Island.
Your mission is to find the treasure.
You're at a crossroad. There are three paths here. Do you want to go west, east, or south?west
You have entered a forest clearing, with a lake in the middle. Do you wait for the ferry, swim across, or go back east?swim
You attempt to swim across, but suddenly you are attacked by a lake monster. Game Over.
```

You are doing most of the things right but one thing that bothers me is that you are using `input(choice1)` or `input(choice2)` in some lines. I guess what you wanted was to take this input again, right? Think about it again because this will simply not work that way.